# Entity model json coming null

Tags: dxa, api

I am trying to create an api where i am trying to get entity model, but I am not able to get the entity model in DXA, my entityID is '3035-3036'
where 3035 is componentid and 3036 is template id

```
model = ContentProvider.GetEntityModel(entityID, WebRequestContext.Localization);
```

if someone can help

Comment: Welcome to Tridion Stack exchange!
Could you tell us more about your CM configuration like your Component Template and it's metadata properties?

Comment: Double-check in broker database Is that component is published with that DCP component template Id?

Comment: Can you share the core.log error message of web app?